# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation Mysql

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-modules, xml-rpc

I am getting the following error message when executing my query:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax near '://www.website.com.br/Manual_01/Realm/1980-1988/R7678.htm' na linha 1: SELECT (field_data_field_url.entity_id) FROM field_data_field_url WHERE field_data_field_url.field_url_value = http//www.website.com.br/Manual_01/Realm/1980-1988/R7678.htm ; Array ( ) em _xmlrpc_troca()
```

this is my function from my Drupal Module:

```
$query = db_query("SELECT (field_data_field_url.entity_id) FROM field_data_field_url WHERE field_data_field_url.field_url_value = $url ");
 foreach ($query as $record) {
 echo $record->entity_id; 
}
 return $record;
```

If I wrap my '$url' with ' ' it works:

```
$query = db_query("SELECT (field_data_field_url.entity_id) FROM field_data_field_url WHERE field_data_field_url.field_url_value = '$url' ");
```

but i get error at xmlrpc response because it sends back the '' and i get error while parsing the response. this response comes with the right data but it´s useless because I can´t parse it.
Someone knows how to fix it?

EDIT:

the response comes like this:

```
body: '30254<?xml version="1.0"?>\n\n<methodResponse>\n  <params>\n  <param>\n    <value><struct>\n  <member><name>entity_id</name><value><string>30254</string></value></member>\n</struct></value>\n  </param>\n  </params>\n</methodResponse>\n\n'
```

This `'30254` and the `'` at the end are the problems. I got this error message:

```
ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 5
```

Comment: What is the data being sent in the response and what does it need to be? (Why can't you parse it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using db_query arguments.

```
<?php $query = db_query('SELECT (field_data_field_url.entity_id) FROM field_data_field_url WHERE field_data_field_url.field_url_value = :url', array(':url' => $url)); ?>
```

You can alsow try using db_select() function.

```
<?php 
$select = db_select('field_data_field_url', 'fdfu'); // fdfu is an alias
$select->fields('fdfu', array('entity_id'));
$select->condition('field_url_value', $url);
$query = $select->execute();

foreach($query as $result) {
   echo $record->entity_id; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but with none of them i got a different result. same error and same situation ( if I don´t use '' I get the same error )

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in select but in insert? How do You insert data to table? Do You use db_insert or db_write_recort?

Comment: All nodes were inserted with a Drupal function $newnode->body etc, this field in DB is correct, as it seems the problem is that I am sending a url an it is making the malfunction. maybe the "//" or other character inside it.